# Calculate change in values over time

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to approximate the tide depth based on depth at high tide and low tide for a range of dates.

```
      date  time depth tide_state     t_datetime
17/03/2018 20:26  0.43        Low 17/03/2018 20:26
18/03/2018 02:33  2.09       High 18/03/2018 02:33
18/03/2018 08:39  0.45        Low 18/03/2018 08:39
18/03/2018 14:47  2.14       High 18/03/2018 14:47
18/03/2018 20:54  0.41        Low 18/03/2018 20:54
19/03/2018 03:01  2.13       High 19/03/2018 03:01
```

I converted `df1$t_datetime` to POSIXct. I then calculated the difference between the times of each tide:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(diff = c(difftime(tail(t_datetime, -1), head(t_datetime, -1)),0))
```

which gives me:

```
     date  time depth tide_state          t_datetime      diff
17/03/2018 20:26  0.43        Low 2018-03-17 20:26:00 6.116667 
18/03/2018 02:33  2.09       High 2018-03-18 02:33:00 6.100000 
18/03/2018 08:39  0.45        Low 2018-03-18 08:39:00 6.133333 
18/03/2018 14:47  2.14       High 2018-03-18 14:47:00 6.116667
18/03/2018 20:54  0.41        Low 2018-03-18 20:54:00 6.116667
19/03/2018 03:01  2.13       High 2018-03-19 03:01:00 6.133333
```

`df1$diff` is in hours.

Using `df1$diff`, I would like to approximately calculate the tidal depth at each hour between the depths listed.

I think I need to calculate the difference in depths between the tides and then divide this by `df1$diff` in order to get the depth change per hour.

Using the first two as an example, the difference in depth is 1.66m. This is ~0.27m per hour.

Ideally my output would be like this:

```
     date  time depth tide_state          t_datetime      diff
17/03/2018 20:26  0.43        Low 2018-03-17 20:26:00 6.116667 
17/03/2018 21:26  0.70        Low 2018-03-17 21:26:00 6.116667 
17/03/2018 22:26  0.97        Low 2018-03-17 22:26:00 6.116667 
17/03/2018 23:26  1.24        Low 2018-03-17 23:26:00 6.116667 
17/03/2018 00:26  1.51        Low 2018-03-17 00:26:00 6.116667 
17/03/2018 01:26  1.78        Low 2018-03-17 01:26:00 6.116667 
18/03/2018 02:33  2.09       High 2018-03-18 02:33:00 6.100000
```

The depths in the above are slightly out as I just used a calculator and didn't include all the extra decimals.

I would like to add extra rows with the new depth. But I'm not sure how I can do this in R as not all of the tidal periods are the same length, and I'm struggling to know how to do it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Data:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("17/03/2018", "18/03/2018", "19/03/2018"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("02:33", 
    "03:01", "08:39", "14:47", "20:26", "20:54"), class = "factor"), 
    depth = c(0.43, 2.09, 0.45, 2.14, 0.41, 2.13), tide_state = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("High", "Low"), class = "factor"), 
    t_datetime = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2018-03-17 20:26:00", 
    "2018-03-18 02:33:00", "2018-03-18 08:39:00", "2018-03-18 14:47:00", 
    "2018-03-18 20:54:00", "2018-03-19 03:01:00"), class = "factor"), 
    diff = c(6.11666666666667, 6.1, 6.13333333333333, 6.11666666666667, 
    6.11666666666667, 6.13333333333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: "UTC" should be added to timezone so `date` + `time` == `t_datetime`.

Comment: Thanks, will add that

Comment: You should also drop some factor levels from you sample data with `droplevels`, or, even better, convert your factors to strings with `as.character`. The actual sample is only 6 rows long, but the above `structure` data is huge because of all the levels. It would also make sense to simply exclude `time` and `date` since we already have both in `t_datetime`

Comment: @gersht I hope it is more helpful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a linear interpolation problem, which would suggest `?approx` to me.

Do some initial setup:

```
dat$t_datetime <- as.POSIXct(dat$t_datetime,tz="UTC")
dat$diff <- c(diff(dat$t_datetime),1)

apptimes <- rep(dat$t_datetime, dat$diff) +
            as.difftime(sequence(dat$diff)-1, units="hours")
```

Have a peak and make sure this worked:

```
apptimes[1:5]
#[1] "2018-03-17 20:26:00 UTC" "2018-03-17 21:26:00 UTC"
#[3] "2018-03-17 22:26:00 UTC" "2018-03-17 23:26:00 UTC"
#[5] "2018-03-18 00:26:00 UTC"
```

Then you can use these `app`roximate `times` to do the linear interpolation of `depth` values:

```
approx(x=dat$t_datetime, y=dat$depth, xout=apptimes)$y
#[1] 0.4300000 0.7013896 0.9727793 1.2441689 1.5155586 1.7869482 2.0900000 ...
```

You can combine this all back together into your master set then:

```
cbind(
    dat[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)),dat$diff), c("X","tide_state")],
    t_datetime = apptimes,
    depth = approx(x=dat$t_datetime, y=dat$depth, xout=apptimes)$y
)
#    X tide_state          t_datetime     depth
#1   1        Low 2018-03-17 20:26:00 0.4300000
#1.1 1        Low 2018-03-17 21:26:00 0.7013896
#1.2 1        Low 2018-03-17 22:26:00 0.9727793
#1.3 1        Low 2018-03-17 23:26:00 1.2441689
#1.4 1        Low 2018-03-18 00:26:00 1.5155586
#1.5 1        Low 2018-03-18 01:26:00 1.7869482
#2   2       High 2018-03-18 02:33:00 2.0900000
## etc etc
```

To show what this is doing, a plot is helpful:

```
plot(dat$t_datetime, dat$depth, xlab="Time", ylab="Depth", col="red", pch=19)
apprdep <- approx(x=dat$t_datetime, y=dat$depth, xout=apptimes)$y
lines(apptimes, apprdep, col="blue", type="o", lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Is there a way to calculate it for multiple tides over multiple days? My full dataset has 387 different tidal periods which I would like to be able to calculate all at once, but as the times are different each day `apptimes[1:7]` may not fit correctly for each tide.

Comment: @Fionn - the `apptimes[1:7]` was just to show you the first few as an example. I've edited for a full set showing hopefully how you can generate all the data for all days.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I'm doing something wrong but I get an error from the `cbind` section: `Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)), dat$diff),  : 
  undefined columns selected`. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @fionn - Sorry, I'll have to take a look in the morning. It's getting late here. It might just be a silly typo from me.

Comment: @Fionn - i've taken a look and the code above looks to work using the data from the question stored in `dat`. It does drop the very last row however - but this is an easy fix to make the `diff` line to `dat$diff <- c(diff(dat$t_datetime),1)` so it gets included. The error sounds like you are referencing a column that is not in `dat`. Can you clarify if the simpler `dat[, c("X","tide_state")]` works?

Comment: I seem to get the same error with `dat[, c("X","tide_state")]`

Comment: @Fionn - take a look at `names(dat)` then - if it doesn't have `"X"` or `"tide_state"`, then remove it or replace it with the name of the column you do want in the output